# How to include POST data in health monitoring email?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, health-monitoring

I am currently using .NET health monitoring classes to email me when server errors occur. However, I am not getting any information about the POST data nor can I find any way to get the POST data from the raised event.

**C#**

```
public class EmailWebEvents : WebEventProvider {

    public override void ProcessEvent(WebBaseEvent raisedEvent) {
        BasicEmail email = new BasicEmail();
        email.To = "your-email@email.com";
        email.Subject = "Website Error (" + Environment.MachineName + ")";
        email.Body = raisedEvent.Message + "\n\n" +
                     raisedEvent.EventSource.ToString() + "\n\n" +
                     raisedEvent.ToString();
        email.Send();
    }

    public override void Shutdown() {
        // Nothing needed to be done.
    }

    public override void Flush() {
        // Nothing needed to be done.
    }
}
```

**Web Config**

```
<system.web>
    <healthMonitoring enabled="true" heartbeatInterval="0">
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="Custom Email Event Provider" type="MvcRoot.Helpers.EmailWebEvents" />
        </providers>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <add name="appDevEvents" eventName="All Errors" provider="Custom Email Event Provider" profile="Critical" minInstances="1" maxLimit="Infinite" minInterval="00:01:00" custom="" />
        </rules>
    </healthMonitoring>
</system.web>
```

How can I include the POST data in these emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a decompiler on `System.Web.Management.WebBaseEvent`. When an event is raised, it makes some direct references to `HttpContext.Current` without any wrapping or helper classes. Then goes onto call your `ProcessEvent` method without spooling up another thread or any of the static classes up. So it seems like `HttpContext.Current` is semi-safe to access from your `ProcessEvent` method.

I'd see if `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` contains the values you're looking for when you're processing the event. You'll probably want to wrap this in some null checks to ensure the context actually exists before trying to pull the form values.